# Instagram token is blocked after some requests

Tags: token, instagram

for our webshop we use an instagram token, which is blocked after a few requests. Therefore the instagram row in our shop is not shown anymore. What we get is the following error message:

**Error Message**

> "You have exceeded the maximum number of requests per hour. You have
>   performed a total of 228 requests in the last hour. Our general
>   maximum limit is set at 200 requests per hour."

Has anyone heared of this before?

Thanks for the support!

Best,
Katja

Comment: The error is pretty much self-explanatory. You are making too many request to their servers. You need to modify your application so that you wouldn't hit that request limit in an hour. For example, you could have a counter for each specific requests your client is performing off that token. Even before the limit is reached, you need to renew or refresh that token.

Comment: Do a request at most every 18 second.